# Check Array Empty Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

In the below Excel VBA script, I have a check that finds whether a range has any blank values (if isEmpty). How do I do a check to determine if ALL The values are blank? I want a separate messagebox to show up if all the fields are  blank telling the user to enter data. but I'm not sure how to enter that.

```
lastRow = Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rBuyerList = Range("O1:O" & lastRow)
arrBuyer = Array("BuyOne", "BuyTwo", "BuyThree", "BuyFour")
For i = 0 To UBound(arrBuyer)
    With Application
        chkFind = .IfError(.Match(Range(arrBuyer(i)), Range("O1:O50"), 0), 0)
    End With
    
    If chkFind = False Then
        If IsEmpty(Range(arrBuyer(i))) = True Then
        Else
        MsgBox "Invalid Buyer Code.." & arrBuyer(i)
        Range(arrBuyer(i)).Select
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: `BuyOne`, `BuyTwo` ...  are named ranges that contain only one cell?

Comment: @FunThomas Correct

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a `Boolean` variable, something like this:

```
Dim allEmpty As Boolean
allEmpty = True

For i = 0 To UBound(arrBuyer)
   If Not IsEmpty(Range(arrBuyer(i))) Then
       allEmpty = False
   End If

   ... 
Next i

If allEmpty Then
    MsgBox "All fields are blank"
End If
```

Comment: this works for the most part but it's telling me all fields are blank even if just one of them are